# May I include another jade template file in one jade template?

Tags: templates, pug

I have a Jade template like:

```
.classA
.classB
   p#id-1
```

And another Jade template like:

```
.classA
.classB
   p#id-2
```

I want to put the following content:

```
.classA
.classB
```

In another Jade file because it's all the same content and by doing this I don't need to change the two jade files twice for each.

Is there anyway to do so?

BTW, it'd be better support variables passing because currently my Jade template contains variables that passed from a JSON object, it's actually like:

```
.classA #{content.common_text1}
.classB #{content.common_text2}
   p#id-1 #{content.key_p}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use blocks for that purpose

main.jade :

```
.classA
  block classA
.classB
  block classB
```

first file :

```
extends main

block classB
  p#id-1 Hey
```

second file :

```
extends main

block classB
  p#id-2 Yo!
```

This is currently missing from the [reference](http://jade-lang.com/reference/) but should be added soon :).

Comment: Thanks, is there any unofficial reference that I can rely on? I now have to guess every details..

Comment: I use [the old readme](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/4b06e294d9630297871b06993bac01d17683f277/Readme.md)

Comment: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/4b06e294d9630297871b06993bac01d17683f277/Readme.md#includes I found this. Isn't `include` easier to use if most of the content are solid/static stuff? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's including VS embedding. Depends on your use case